# Is there a reference for this integral

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals, fourier-series

what is the value of this integral:

$\int_{-1}^{1}
(a-x)^{-u} (1-x^2)^{u-v} dx $ with $|a|>1; u=-c-k,v=k+\frac{n-3}{2}; (n,k)\in \Bbb{N}$ and $c\in\Bbb{R}^+$

Thank a lot of.

Comment: Do you have any constraints on $a,u,v$?

Comment: Yes,  we suppose $|a|>1$.

Comment: Integer, rational, real, or complex?

Comment: $u,v\in \Bbb(R)$